# How to add link in if-else format in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create links in sessions but failed to perform: my code:

```
<?php
$link =<a href=login.php>LOGIN HERE</a>;
?>
```

but it says error in line

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes:

```
<?php
$link = '<a href="login.php">LOGIN HERE</a>';
?>
```

The above is valid, but most likely not what you want. I cannot say more since I don't see where there are any conditionals (if/else) involved here...

If you want to display the link in a browser instead of saving it in the variable `$link` then use that as a starting point instead:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="login.php">LOGIN HERE</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better still, use this :

`<?php`
   
`if (some_condition_is_true) { // Start the condition`
 `?>`

`<a href="login.php">LOGIN HERE</a>`

`<?php 
   } // End the condition
?>`

This, although means the same, it proves to be an easier way for the browser and the php engine to toggle between `<?php?>` and `html` tags

Comment: Mine is an approx answer and that too an addition to the answer posted by @arkascha. In order to have a closer answer, I request you to use this http://www.jsfiddle.net/ to show some sample in case your problem relates to html.